# keystrokes with Google Chrome/Firefox and Selenium not working in Python

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, firefox, keystroke

Run the following:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

# Get web driver going
cp = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
cp.add_argument("--browser.download.folderList=2")
cp.add_argument("--browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk=image/jpg")
cp.add_argument("--browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk=image/png")
cp.add_argument("--browser.download.dir=~/Downloads/")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=cp)

driver.get("http://www.google.com")
# Try to open a new tab
driver.find_element_by_tag_name("body").send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, 't')
```

This was an attempt to open a new tab, but the code does not work. This is also the case when trying to use Firefox. For Firefox, this *does* work if I don't change the profile (using equivalent code), but does not work with a custom profile.

I would also like to be able to send `Ctrl+S` too, but it seems no commands involving a special character work (though I can still `send_keys` normal text, not involving special keys like `Ctrl`).

What can I do to be able to send `Ctrl+T` and `Ctrl+S` (*especially* the latter)?

Answer (score -1):

You can use action chain as given below.

```
ActionChains(driver).key_down(Keys.CONTROL).send_keys('s').key_up(Keys.CONTROL).perform()
```

Comment: This does not work, either for simulating `Ctrl+S` (as your solution does) or `Ctrl+T`.