# Saving pages with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome

I will try again.

The code below I copied from another site and the user say it works (shows a screenshot).[Original code](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/33407/how-to-save-an-webpage-as-a-xml-file-using-python-and-selenium)

I tested the code: No error, but no file save.

All questions use this answer to save a file: [A question!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44664044/keystrokes-with-google-chrome-firefox-and-selenium-not-working-in-python)

why the page is not saved or, if it is, where is the file?

Thanks

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Selenium\chromedriver.exe")

driver.get("http://www.example.com")

saveas = ActionChains(driver).key_down(Keys.CONTROL).send_keys('S').key_up(Keys.CONTROL)

saveas.perform()
```

Answer (score 3):

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Selenium\chromedriver.exe")

driver.get("http://www.example.com")
with open('page.html', 'w+') as f:
    f.write(driver.page_source)
```

Must work

Answer (score 2):

If you do the key combination in the browser, you will see this only brings up the 'save page' dialog box. You need to additionally send ALT+S to save the page, in Windows it will be saved in your Downloads folder by default.

```
saveas = ActionChains(driver).key_down(Keys.CONTROL).send_keys('S').key_up(Keys.CONTROL).send_keys('MyDocumentName').key_down(Keys.ALT).send_keys('S').key_up(Keys.ALT)
```

EDIT:
ActionChains are unreliable. It would be easier not to interact with the browser GUI.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Selenium\chromedriver.exe")

driver.get("http://www.example.com")
with open('page.html', 'w') as f:
    f.write(driver.page_source)
```

Comment: It appears to be version dependent. Confirmed not working on newest Chrome and Firefox.