# CTRL S to save a chrome page contents using selenium python not working

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to use CTRL + S in selenium to save contents of a page but can't get anything happening. If I try to do it using my keyboard the save window opens.

```
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
action_chains = ActionChains(driver)
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 

options.add_argument("download.default_directory=C:/Downloads, download.prompt_for_download=False")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)


driver.get("https://imagecyborg.com/")

action_chains.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL).send_keys("s").perform()
```

Comment: Does this answer work? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52142180/saving-pages-with-selenium

Comment: If you try with key_down(value, element=None)[source]   https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver/selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.html

Comment: Tried changing to key down and getting the same

Comment: Look at mermaldad's answer. If that doesn't work for you, depending on what you're trying to do you could programmatically save the dom, or use browsermob proxy to capture the request contents (which is NOT going to be the same as the fully rendered page of course)

Comment: His link doesnt have a solution. To be more specific I have a link as follows: s3.amazon.com/bucketname/1233. Note the link doesnt have the file name  or extensions. Only when I right click and save I am able to know the type. Some links are jpg, some are webp, others are video. In some cases you can t see page source to get the source url. So only way left was to automate the ctrl s which isnt working

Answer (score 5):

The only thing that worked for me was pyautogui:

```
import pyautogui
pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl','s')
pyautogui.press('enter')
```

Comment: I had to add a time.sleep() (page takes a while toload) but this does work for me :)

Comment: @steveman, do you still have this code?

Comment: @punky I just now read your question

ffprofile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile(
    "<path to firefox profile>")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=ffprofile)
driver.get(<URL>)
pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 's')
sleep(3) #the sleep I mentioned here
pyautogui.press('enter')