# Download website (bulk quantity) HTML source code

Tags: html, download

There are many websites, I have treid to download website HTML source code, but I am looking for an approach to download website (bulk quantity) HTML source code in batch.

Please suggest if there is any website or approach to download bulk website source code.

Note: I want to download only HTML codes of only home pages.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can give HTTrack a try https://www.httrack.com/

Simplest way is to open the webpage in your browser and go to File -> Save Page As -> Web Page Complete (*.html) and save it on your hard drive.

In  chrome its on the right click menu on the page

[image]

Comment: File -> Save Page As -> Web Page Complete (*.html) and save it on your hard drive.------- This is a manual job, BUT I want the same auto job for multiple sites. There are many sites that allow to download HTML source of single website at a time. Is there site, you know that allows to downlaod HTML source of multiple sites at a time?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `Selenium` module to initialize a chrome driver within a Python environment, for example.

While such tools are designed to parse website data/content, you can simply let the driver access the website (URL) and merely save the HTML source code to a file.

In pseudo code, the approach would be

- Set up an executable environment, for example python
- Initialize a driver through selenium
- Define your list of websites (URLs) that you would like to visit & save into a variable
- Make a for loop that goes through your list of URLs
- . Step 1: For each URL in the list, let chromedriver access the website
- . Step 2: Save the HTML code to a file (like shown here: [Saving pages with Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52142180/saving-pages-with-selenium))